# Alternative method to determine if there is textual data in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have several sheets wherein I need to ensure and validate that all the 'numbers' (values) within predetermined ranges are actually numbers. We can assume that all numeric values are valid. The ranges however are not exactly predetermined, since the are re-populated daily with new data imports so that will mean more rows - however the starting cell reference, O3 is expected to always be the same.

Currently I am using `COUNT(O3:BB1740)` and `COUNTA(O3:BB1740)` and then finding the difference between the two values (if the difference is not zero it indicates that there is data within the range that is not numeric).

This method seems hackish to me so I am looking for a reasonable alternative.

- If possible, how would I isolate and identify the invalid value (I know I can loop though each cell but I am looking for a non-macro approach if possible)

*(It would be awesome if there was a `IsNumber` function for ranges)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more elegant way is to use an array formula. This will return TRUE if every number in *range* is a number or FALSE if *range* contains non-numbers or blanks.

```
{=AND(ISNUMBER(range))}
```

To isolate the non-number values in the range you can apply Conditional Formatting using a similar formula.

Hint: To create an array formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering/editing the cell.

Comment: Is there any way to exclude blanks?

Comment: one issue, excel constantly complains about running out of memory when using this function. i do however have several sheets which uses this function...

Comment: @Ahmad: Not as simply. You could use a function that requires all numbers or blanks as input, such as GCD() in a formula like =ISNUMBER(GCD(range)) (not an array formula). It is shorter than your orignal idea but still 'hackish' :)

Comment: @Ahmad: I didn't notice your range was so large. I am surprised my first solution gives you memory errors but, given that it does, I wouldn't recommend my second GCD solution either. If your own solution is working then you should probably stick with it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i guess that array formulas are volatile. What i did though was to run the formula from a macro for each sheet, but immediately remove it after I got the result.